# Adding a glyphicon button to the side of a list-group-item

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Given the standard bootstrap list-group-item:

```
        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
            <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          <small class="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
        </div>
```

What's the best way to add a remove icon to sit on the right hand inside the list-group-item? float has ruined the styling of the div.
Here's the button I'd like to add:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>
```

I'm sort of new to bootstrap I tried making columns inside the listgroup item but that had poor results as well.

Answer (score 1):

This code using span worked for me though I don't like that the icon is tied to the headings vertical position even though in this use case it doesn't matter.

```
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
            <span class="pull-right">
              <span class="btn btn-lrg btn-danger" onclick="">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </span>
          </span>
            <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          <small class="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css property:

```
display: inline-block
```

it will resolve the issue.

Comment: sorry I should use that on which dom?